# How to create a Vector of Vectors within a For-Loop?

Tags: for-loop, vector, multidimensional-array, rust, iteration

I'm trying to create a vector of vectors using for-loops. I'm tried the design below but to no success:

```
// num_partitions is the primary vector, v is vector that contains a set of integers
// This function should return a Primary Vector that hold num_partitions of vectors

fn partition_data(num_partitions: usize, v: &Vec<usize>) -> Vec<Vec<usize>> {
    let partition_size = v.len() / num_partitions;

    // Create a vector that will contain vectors of integers
    let mut xs: Vec<Vec<usize>> = Vec::new();
 
    for j in 0..partition_size {
        for i in 0..partition_size {
            // create a new Vector and push elements to it
            let mut x1: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
            x1.push(v[i]);
        }
        // push this new Vector the the Primary Vector
        xs.push(x1);
    }
   
    // return primary vector
    xs
}
```

Comment: You don't actually explain what the issue is, or provide a repro case, however I expect that to not compile as Rust is strictly block-scoped. Since you're declaring `x1` in the inner-most loop, it only lives for one iteration of said innermost loop. That declaration needs to be lifted one scope.

Comment: That aside, your code doesn't make much sense: it's just going to create `partition_size` vectors all holding the first `partition_size` items from the input vector.

Comment: And taking an input `&Vec<T>` is not usually useful, `&[T]` provides more caller flexibility with no drawbacks.

Comment: `x1` should be declared in the outer `for` loop, not in the inner one. This probably doesn't compile because `xs.push(x1)` refers to a variable that doesn't exist in that scope. That is not a Rust-specific issue, you would have the same or similar problem in Java, Python, C++, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are handy functions in the Rust standard library that already do most of what you need to implement this function easily using just Iterators:

```rust
fn partition_data(num_partitions: usize, v: &Vec<usize>) -> Vec<Vec<usize>> {
    let partition_size = v.len() / num_partitions;
    v.chunks(partition_size)
        .map(|chunk| chunk.to_vec())
        .collect()
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cbd76f46db6425839ed4f0a5d36c5e23)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified example of your problem:

```rust
let mut outer_vec: Vec<Vec<usize>> = Vec::new();
for j in 0..5 {
  for i in 0..5 {     
    let mut inner_vec: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
    inner_vec.push(1);
  }
  outer_vec.push(inner_vec);
}
```

`inner_vec` is declared in the inner `for` loop. `outer_vec` is declared in the *outer* `for`  loop. Due to Rust's [scoping and ownership rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope.html), `inner_vec` is destroyed at the end of it's scope (the inner `for` loop), and therefore the outer scope (the outer `for` loop) cannot access it:

```rust
for i in 0..5 {
  let mut inner_vec: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
  // inner_vec is valid from here ^
  inner_vec.push(1);
  // inner_vec is destroyed here, it's memory is freed
}
// inner_vec is now non-existent, so this fails:
outer_vec.push(inner_vec);
```

To fix this, you can declare `inner_vec` in the outer scope:

```rust
let mut inner_vec: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
for i in 0..5 {
  inner_vec.push(1);
}
// inner_vec and outer_vec are now in the same scope, so this is fine:
outer_vec.push(inner_vec);
```